# Accessing YouTube account for stats from Google Cloud via API

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have a YouTube channel with mymanager@gmail.com as the manager.
I have set up a Google Cloud account for my domain ssss.org (Free trial).
I have written OAuth code to access the YT API and activated YT APIs.
I run the code and authenticate as me@ssss.org.
I called:

```
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
try {
  $channel = $youtube->channels->listChannels('snippet', ['mine' => TRUE]);...
```

and got the exception  message: `"Unauthorized", "errors": [ { "message": "Unauthorized", "domain": "youtube.header", "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired", "location": "Authorization", "locationType": "header" }`

I added me@ssss.org as a manager on the YT account and clicked the link in the ‘Invitation to access xxx’ email.
This was ok but then gave error referring to https://support.google.com/a/answer/9000768 which is about G Suite trials.

What is best way to link GC with my YT account?

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud and YouTube really have nothing to do with each other.  Im not really sure what you are trying to do with it.

## Unauthorized error

Sounds like you haven't set up the authorization properly.  It should popup and request authorization of the user. You need to login to your code with the user that has access to the data you wish to see.

In this case if you want to see the channels owned by mymanager@gmail.com then you would login as mymanager@gmail.com.

> This example retrieves the channel data for the authorized user's YouTube channel. It uses the mine request parameter to indicate that the API should only return channels owned by the user authorizing the request.

mine only works with channels that are owned by the user you are logging in as.

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

}
```

## Google workspace

[Access to YouTube during your Google Workspace trial](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9000768)

> Your Google Workspace account has been billed for at least USD $30 (or equivalent in your currency). This amount doesn’t include the cost to purchase your domain.

> If you’ve had your account for 30 days and you signed up for Google Workspace directly from Google: You can make an early payment or pay for more users accounts to access all YouTube features. After you make the payment, it might take up to 48 hours before features are available.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo -  I have to use OAuth in order to get the YT statistics I need - according to the docs.  I have authenticated as you suggest, ie get the popup etc.  If I try to open the YT studio when logged in as mymanager@ I get the message saying I cant access and quoting  https://support.google.com/a/answer/9000768  - which I think is the real issue. But I need to get round this while I'm doing the free trial in order to prove that it all works. How do I do this?

Comment: @Jons SO is not Google support you wont get a response from Google here.

Comment: @DalmTo you are 'Google Developer Expert for Google Analytics and Identity platform' and thanks for responding -  how do I get support as this is the area we're told to go to by Google Cloud

Comment: The page you posted mentions waiting thirty days before you will be able to use this feature.  I sugest you wait thirtydays.

Comment: @DalmTo  - yes but the page also says: "Why is access limited? 

To keep our systems healthy, we have minimum requirements for Google Workspace accounts to upload videos, add comments, create a channel, and other actions that require being signed into an account."    This does not seem to make sense as its got notthing to do with waiting 30 days (which itself seems a strange, randon restriction). All these things are in place on my channel - all I want to do is access it!

Answer (score 0):

I did get this to work using OAuth, and as I'd run out of free trial time I upgraded to the nearest paid level.  It's tricky to get right - especially when its not clear what 'right' is. See [Need details of credentials setup for Analytics and Reporting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691823/need-details-of-credentials-setup-for-analytics-and-reporting-api) for more info.